# How to stop all CSS overrides on a container DIV?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a container div which i add to external websites using a bookmarklet to do some functions, the problem i face that this div contains some elements and each element has its inline style, but when i put in the external site, sometimes it overrides styles from the site CSS.

There is a way to stop any overrides on this div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can define css properites within the element to be able to display your div properly e.g.

```
<div style="margin:0;border:1px solid red;">
```

Or additionally you can supply your css styles with your Div html as well.

I know its a pain when the "external" site has css global rules; e.g

```
ul ( margin-left: 5px; }
```

the best I could do was to reset all these things for my div id.

UPDATE:

Yes, I understand that he has inline styles but the problem is caused by global rules. So e.g. if @Amr ElGarhy's div has ULs, they will all get left margin of 5px (as I exampled above). and Amr ElGarhy has to reset this margin in inline styles as well.

Comment: so, i can understand from your answer, that i i should add all possible styles inline in my tags to avoid overrides? :(

Comment: While it seams that this is the only solution i found as well, but lets wait sometime, may be someone else come with a geek solution.

Answer (score 3):

The host site should have it's CSS properties defined with the **!important** notice (color: red !important;).

Or you could append your styles to the DIV using JavaScript (**jQuery**). You can check if the DIV already has styling so you can decide to add or not to add any of your styling.

Answer (score 0):

If !important has been used (bad) by the hosting site then you are reduced to inline styles (bad again) but hey.

If they have not and an example of what you are trying to over-ride is like another poster said:

```
ul ( margin-left: 5px; }
```

then you can simply use selector weighting to make sure your style is heavier than theirs i.e.

```
#mycontainingDivElement ul { blah:blah }
```

because your style has more levels (and note certain things in css have different weights i.e. ids vs class selectors) it will be used regardless of position in css sheet order